# Fmax, Dmax. How do I put the "max" as a subscript?

Tags: unicode, fonts, plot, label, subscript

In Python I am currently plotting some data and extracting the maximum values.
now i want to have a label which looks like this:
`Fmax = ...` and  `Dmax = ...`, except for the max being a subscript, like "down".

The label currently looks like this:

> a1.plot(z, k, label = "Kraft [Fmax: %s N], "%(round(max(k))))

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode has some subscript letters:

```
u'Kraft [Fₘₐₓ: %s N], '
u'Kraft [F\u2098\u2090\u2093: %s N], ' # same value escaped for ASCII-safe source
```

but you would need to be using a font that supported them.

Otherwise, you would be dependent on whatever text formatting features are provided by whatever the graphics library you are using is; if none then you would have to place the `max` yourself manually in a smaller font at the right position.